# php regex pairing words and numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have some structured words and numbers separated by / and there is a space between words and numbers.

```
$string1 = "blabla apple/banana/cherry 15/33/45,2 blabla ";
$string2 = "blabla orange/yellow/green/black 92/149.7/204/16 another string blabla";
```

I want to pair words and numbers, respectively. (etc banana and 33 or black and 16 or orange and 92). I tried with the below code for banana but it doesn't give proper results.

```
$pattern = "%(\w+)/?banana(/?(\w+))*(\s)(\d+/?)*%iU";
$matches = preg_split($pattern, $string1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => blabla 
    [1] => 15/33/45,2 blabla 
)
```

Comment: What should be returned?

Comment: for apple=>15, cherry =>45,2, yellow =>149.7 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sLbcHF/1/)

The assumption is that in the second grouping we can have digits, comma and decimal point, i.e. `[\d,.]+`.

```
<?php
$tests = [
    "blabla apple/banana/cherry 15/33/45,2 blabla ",
    "blabla orange/yellow/green/black 92/149.7/204/16 another string blabla"
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match('%\b(\w+(?:/(?:\w+))*) ([\d,.]+(?:/(?:[\d,.]+))*)\b%', $test, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        $arr1 = explode('/', $matches[1]);
        $arr2 = explode('/', $matches[2]);
        $results = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
            $results[$arr1[$i]] = $arr2[$i];
        }
        print_r($results);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => 15
    [banana] => 33
    [cherry] => 45,2
)
Array
(
    [orange] => 92
    [yellow] => 149.7
    [green] => 204
    [black] => 16
)
```

Comment: That's exactly I want. You saved my day. Thank you.